# How can I make sure that there is no limit to how long a password can be?

Tags: c

I wrote a code in C where the user has to have a "$", a number and a capital number in their password for it to be valid, but I'm confused as to what to do so that the password can be as long as they want, without me having to write `char password[100000000000]`or something like that.

```
int something = 100;
char password[something];
int index = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;

printf("Enter Password: "); //Mike$4
scanf("%s", password);

do{ // If index is strlen, then we checked every char of pw
    // Ex. Password is length 6, then index 0 - 5 will be checked
    if(index == strlen(password) && x>0 && y>0 && z>0){
        printf("Good password!");
        break;
    }
    if(index == strlen(password) && (x==0 || y==0 || z==0)){
        printf("BAD PASSWORD");
        break;
    }

    if(isupper(password[index]) ||  isdigit(password[index]) ||
       password[index] == '$'){

         if(isupper(password[index])){
                x++; index++;
                continue;}
         if(isdigit(password[index])){
                y++; index++;
                continue;}
         if(password[index] == '$'){
                z++; index++;
                continue;}
    }else{index++;
          continue;
          }
}while(index <= strlen(password));
```

This is my code. Thanks!

Comment: Build a computer with unlimited memory. Or move to dynamic allocation of the string. Note, on some UNIX systems you can use `m` "directive" with scanf `%s` modifier like `%ms`.

Comment: @KenWhite but you can allocate it chunk-by-chunk (even character-by-character) and don't waste a single byte

Comment: @KenWhite I don't waste anything, I just correct your comments

Comment: "no limit to how long a password can be" is a mis-guided goal. An unlimited length password is a hacker's delight as it allows external control to overwhelm memory resources. Set a generous upper bound instead like 256.  Or do you like [Star Trek (Data's Password)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DT56m5_PSDA)?

Comment: @KamilCuk: Passwords of arbitrary length can be processed with limited memory and without dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Ken: No, memory to store the entire password does not have to be allocated at all, whether statically, dynamically, or otherwise. It is not necessary to have storage for all the characters of a password.

Comment: @KenWhite: The requirements of the problem are not to validate that an entered string is the password to some account. The requirements of the problem are to test whether a string entered as a proposed password satisfies policy requirements that the password contains at least one dollar sign, one number sign, and one uppercase letter. It is a student exercise in processing characters and writing simple loops and tests. It does not call for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @Eric: This discussion is just noise now, and doesn't add anything here. I've deleted my comments (all of them) to remove the clutter.

Comment: @chux Ah you're right I really should, my bad. I usually ask questions at the end of my coding sessions and then go to sleep, and when I wake up it's already been a long time between answers so I don't bother answering. I will try my best to stop that habit though, thanks for bringing it to my attention :)

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want unlimited length (although its utility is somewhat questionable -- it's probably better to just pick a big limit and be done with it), you're going to have to ditch `scanf` for something like `fgets` that allows you to specify how many characters to read, then read the input in chunks. You'll probably want to use an easy-to-grow structure (like a linked list of slightly-less-than-page-sized string buffers) to read in these chunks, then allocate a buffer for the final string once you hit a newline (or EOF, depending on your desired semantics) in your input.

Comment: Yeah for passwords I guess it isn't terribly useful, but I was just wondering if there was a way for me to set an undefined length I guess, rather than "unlimited length".

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use `fgets`. Note that `scanf("%s")` will only get a single word and some passwords might have spaces. But, the real reason to use `fgets` is that you can prevent overflow as in:

```
char password[1000];
fgets(password,sizeof(password),stdin);
char *cp = strchr(password,'\n');
if (cp != NULL)
    *cp = 0;
```

That's the simplest solution.

But, if you *really* need a *large* password [of unspecified length], you can grow the `password` variable from `realloc`, just as would be done for a dynamic array:

```
char *password = NULL;
int pwmax = 0;
int pwlen = 0;

void *
xrealloc(void *ptr,size_t len)
{
    void *tmp;

    tmp = realloc(ptr,len);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        free(ptr);
        exit(1);
    }

    return ptr;
}

while (1) {
    int chr = fgetc(stdin);
    if (chr == EOF)
        break;
    if (chr == '\n')
        break;

    if (pwlen >= pwmax) {
        if (pwlen >= 1000000) {
            fprintf(stderr,"password beyond reasonable max limit\n")
            exit(1);
        }
        pwmax += 100;
        password = xrealloc(password,pwmax);
    }

    password[pwlen++] = chr;
}

password = xrealloc(password,pwlen + 1);
password[pwlen] = 0;
```

Comment: Or, if available, just use POSIX `getline` for the same effect, but see @chux comment to the original question. `password = realloc(password, ...` bad, `void *tmp = realloc (password, ...` and then `if (tmp) password = tmp;` better...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm aware of `realloc`'s "fail" behavior, but I'm not in the "you can _meaningfully_ recover from it" camp. So, best to just abort. I tire of doing the full `realloc` code recovery here, but just to keep the peace ...

Comment: But you can. If `realloc` returns `NULL`, your original block of memory is still valid and can be referenced and freed via `password`. If you let `realloc` set `password = NULL;` on failure, you create a memory leak by losing the address held by `password`. That's what you are protecting against by reallocating with a temporary variable and how you recover. Granted in trivial programs, it is unlikely to happen, but that doesn't save you when the code gets moved into an app that can (and does) exhaust memory leading to a `realloc` fail.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's not about the `realloc` behavior (re. its return). It's about if you can't allocate what you need, how can the program _meaningfully_ proceed? It needs to store something and can't get the memory to do so. So, what does it do (other than abort)? Some [_carefully_ crafted] programs can call a function that tries to free some objects to make some room (e.g. they're just a database cache and they can be flushed), but usually `malloc` failure is terminal condition from a practical standpoint.

Comment: Ok, I see we are talking about two different sides of the same coin - yes, if you can't `realloc` you can't proceed, but I was talking about handling a failure (and whatever cleanup is needed) gracefully without an `exit(1);`. So yes, I see what you are saying, I was just looking at the other side where the failed password entry for a new user wouldn't  justify a complete exit from the program.

Answer (score 0):

Simply process one character of the password at a time; there is no need to have it all in memory at once.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter password: ");

    bool SawDollar = false;
    bool SawDigit  = false;
    bool SawUpper  = false;

    while (1)
    {
        int c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF || isspace(c))
            break;

        if (c == '$')
            SawDollar = true;
        else if (isdigit(c))
            SawDigit = true;
        else if (isupper(c))
            SawUpper = true;
    }

    if (SawDollar && SawDigit && SawUpper)
        printf("Good password!\n");
    else
        printf("Bad password.\n");
}
```